# How to get a subset of Mathew Hansen dataset in projected co-ordinate system

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, coordinate-system, raster-conversion

As we know from the metadata of the Global forest datasets created by Mathew Hansen, et. al., that can be found [here](https://earthenginepartners.appspot.com/science-2013-global-forest), this data is derived from the landsat data. So the spatial resolution of this data should be 30 by 30 meter.But the problem is they are not- or maybe I am on the wrong boat.

This data comes in WGS84 projection system but when I reproject subset of this data into PCS(UTM46), I do not get the 30 by 30 resolution rather ~25m.

More dangerously, when I just extract by mask this dataset to my region of interest it gets displaced as the below visual.The mask featureclass is of same projection system i.e. WGS84 just like the Hansen dataset.

[image: displacement]

---

**Now can anyone help me with what the correct/scientific way of getting raster dataset for specific area(subset, UTM46) in projected co-ordinate system from this Hansen dataset?**

Comment: I think you're on the wrong boat. Geographic data that is nominally denoted in degrees doesn't have a fixed size in meters. Sweating a difference between 30m and 25m without stating the latitude deprives us of the ability to explain where you've departed for that boat. You get a subset of global raster data in a new projection by clipping the area around AOI, projecting, then clipping again, to "square up" the raster.  You can specify a pixel size (indeed, you should), but you have to realize that interpolation is occurring to generate each pixel.

Comment: I don't get the right path seeing wake! Downloaded global dataset is in WGS84 and I clipped( Extract by mask in ArcMAP) this with another featureclass that has exact same projection, WGS84 , in ArcMAP. Even after this the pixels are being displaced!  Now could you suggest the right path to follow and please thereby maintain your Captaincy. Thanks

Comment: When you reproject data that is in lat/long the software takes a guess at the correct resolution, and is sometimes wildly off. You have to explicitly define the x,y cell dimensions. Also, you cannot objectively assess accuracy and offset when using "on the fly" projections in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to solve addressed problem. Just use `arcpy.env.snapRaster = input_raster_path` if you are in scripting environment. But if you are in gui mode/using tool the set the parameters as below:

[image: snap to raster form]